# Two separate path for python when I use which python

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-2.7, homebrew

I installed python using the command:
    brew install python3

Now when I use 'which python', path is '/usr/bin/python' and when I use 'which python3' path is 'usr/local/bin/python3'

Shouldn't it fetch the same path ? 
As python3, which is a version, still falls under python ?

I just am not clear as to why different paths are thrown. Please Explain!

Comment: you have two versions of python installed : python 2.x and python 3 you can specify which version you want to use by running python or python3

Comment: Python 3 doesn't replace Python 2. The same with subversions - ie, 3.7 doesn't replace 3.6. At this momen I have commands `python`, `python2`, `python2.7`, `python3`, `python3.6`, `python3.7`. And the same is with `pip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is a program, that will take inputs, and interpret them. How will it interpret them ? Following a set of rules, written in a lot of files. Where are these files written ? Somewhere the program knows. And by default, the 2 paths you have are the paths it knows where to go.

Python2 and Python3 have different files, because even if they have the same base, they are not same and behave differently. Hence the 2 differents paths.

Though, through the years, people have come up with solution to avoid these "python version collisions" on computers : it is called a virtualenv.

Virtualenv is basically a script that will contain a whole new python (at the version you wish you install it), and, when you "activate" it, you will be able to use `python`, and have the version you wish to develop with. Doing this, everyone is able to only use `python` and still use different versions depending of the program you with to use.

Example : You have `python` on your system which writes `Python 2.7.12` when you do `python --version`. If you instantiate your virtualenv (see the doc), and then use `python --version` again, you might see something else along the lines of `Python 3.6.8`. Your former computer, or other scripts, can still use the previous python version, and you new script can use the new one, without any conflicts.